# Original language of Lo Straniero

Tags: dubbing, lo-straniero

IMDb and Wikipedia say the movie *Lo Straniero* ("The Stranger") by Visconti was originally in French and Italian, but I can only find it in Italian.
I'm wondering if it was really multilingual and, if so, why this was the case, and how I can find out which scenes where later dubbed.

Comment: Many Italian productions filmed in multiple languages (usually the actor's native tongue) then dubbed into a single language after the fact. There may be no record of dubs/changes, or a French version.